# Computer freezing, lagging and crashing randomly

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, crash, event-viewer

My 3 year old computer is recently crashing multiple times each day with no tracable sources. It happens randomly; when gaming, watching videos or even idling... The temperature is of the CPU is fine. The same goes for the GPU. The CPU up-time is also not consistent each time it crashes. It sometimes crashes after 5 minutes or after 1.5 hours. My mouse and sound starts to lag and then after a couple of seconds, my screen goes completely black (or with weird glitchy blocks / bars). Sometimes I am forced to restart it myself by holding the power button, but most of the time it restarts by itself. Rarely I get a BSOD, where the error message is also very inconsistant... The latest BSOD I got was yesterday. It said **"Video scheduler internal error"**

I am supecting the GPU but at this point I am completely lost after what I've tried.

- Monitoring GPU-Z to watch for tempature (stays between [40 degrees idle and 70 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UojPR.jpg) while gaming)
- Updating GPU drivers
- Updating motherboard drivers
- Installing GPU software to lower the clockspeed and temperature threshold (Gigabyte GTX 1080)
- Reinstalling Windows 10 (did this twice on 2 different disks; M.2 and regular SSD, both 500GB)
- Reinstalling GPU drivers (using the DDU method)
- Analized Event Viewer and Reliability Monitor data after crashes
- Ran a memory check  (no issues)
- Ran a disk check (no issues)
- Removed all the PC housing panels and removed some dust (to make sure it isn't an overheating issue)

See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue3ET.jpg 
The spike in the GPU 3D section was when my PC started freezing / lagging. I thought it was crashing again, but it recovered it self somehow (no errors in the Event Viewer). While this was happening, the screen went black and I was seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK0X6.jpg) (captured this with my phone)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP1LD.jpg) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jggy.jpg) image shows the Reliability Monitor after a full crash (with restarting)

What else can I do to fix/trace this problem? I can't switch GPU's with someone else to check wether it is the GPU or not. I am also not going to buy a new GPU for 400-500 euro's without knowing for sure that it actually is the GPU..

If some information is missing, feel free to ask! :)

### Setup

Memory: G.Skill Trident Z RGB F4-2400C15D-16GTZR (2x8GB) 
CPU: Intel Core i7 7700K - 4.2 GHz 
PSU: Corsair SF Series SF600 
Motherboard: Asus ROG Strix Z270I Gaming Mini-ITX  
Storage: Crucial MX300 M.2 SSD and another regular 500GB SSD  
GPU: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1080 G1 Gaming

Comment: Three things you can check to make sure you haven't missed something on the hardware front: 1) Your screen refresh rate. Is it compatible with your GPU 3D settings? 2) Is your GPU properly seated in your motherboard, with all the circuitry in the right place? 3) Is your PSU strong enough for your hardware? Could be that the power it delivers is too weak, or doesn't provide the right voltage (it's rarely an intensity/amperage problem, in those cases), or surges on boot then decreases.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I forgot to tell that my PC is already 3 years old and started doing this since a couple of months. I've edited the question, sorry! Voltages seems correct (at least it tells me in the BIOS; 3.3V, 5V and 12V show pertty accurate readings)

Comment: What about your RAM voltage? Should be 1.5V, but if for some reason you install 1.35V (Low Power RAM), then you're bound to have a problem or two.

Comment: Hello Didier. I've checked my BIOS and it says that it is set to auto (which is 1.2V). Also, on the packaging of my RAM (DDR4 2133Mhz, 2x8GB) that it is 1.2V memory. Do you recommend changing it to 1.35V/1.5V or leave it as it is?

Comment: I have checked my order history and can confirm that I am using G.Skill Trident Z RGB F4-2400C15D-16GTZR memory. They advertise them as 2400Mhz although task manager says 2133Mhz?

Comment: If you RAM is operating under the right voltage, and your mobo is cool with that, not trying to correct/overvolt it, then don't change a thing. I found a topic about a similar problem on a French website where they say you have to uninstall the driver AND your NVIDIA profile, then perform a clean install of the whole package. Here's the link to the uninstall tool: https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html. Of course, better have the new driver package handy to reinstall. Visit the NVIDIA website for that. Also says not to install NVIDIA GeForce Experience".